# Django-filer, URL that is 'seperate' from admin

Tags: django, django-filer

I am trying to set up django-filer on my website.  I cannot figure out how to get the URLS to be separate from the admin site on the website.

localhost:8000/admin/filer/folder/

Is where it wants to go now, which of course requires someone to have complete admin access in the /admin portion.  I want them to have just filer access and be able to see the site.   I have my base urls.py as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')), # new
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), 
    path('filer/', include('filer.server.urls')),
]
```

Going to localhost:8000/filer does nothing though?  I was hoping I was able to create a local little dropbox functionality with my django website where registered users can use it, though they don't have to be admin in the /admin

Is this even possible?  I didn't see it in the documentation for filer at all?

Comment: Hey Codejoy, I know it's been almost a year since you posted this but did you by any chance find a way to accomplish this? I'm looking to do something very similar and would love to communicate. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When I looked into the source code of [django-filer](https://github.com/divio/django-filer) I felt, it will be very hard to ***re-implement*** these kinds of operations outside the Django Admin.

So, I would like to implement a different solution... **Allow non-staff users to access the Django admin, but only to this particular app**

For that, we need to [override the default admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site).

```
# myproject/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    login_form = AuthenticationForm

    def has_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.is_active

# myproject/apps.py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'

# myproject/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

**Notes:**

- Why override `login_form` and `has_permission(...)`?

  - By default Django checks `is_staff` flag. In our cases, **we need to allow all authenticated users**

As of now, for a ***non-staff user*** can log in to the Django Admin and he will able to see an empty Django dashboard as below

[image: non-staff user login]

Now we need to handle the permissions. For that, I am using Group Permissions schemes. So,

- Create a Group
- Add *all `filer` app permissions* to the group
- Add normal user to the *Filer* group

[image: add permissions to group]

[image: add user to the group]

and now finally, for a normal user, the Django Admin will look like,

[image: final result]

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer. I am a bit new to Django, so forgive if this is a stupid question, but how then might I configure my URLs to route directly to the django-filer admin widget (circumventing the admin panel altogether)?

Comment: If I understood correctly, You can not have a ***filter specific URLs*** for a normal user. For everyone, the URL will be the same, But the permissions decide which app/model to be shown to the logged-ibn user.